# When I try to scrape from website I don't get information which I need. Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know that it depends on the situation how I scrape info from the website but I don't know how to do it on this website in the code. As you can see I want to get the price, name and the opinion and put it into the DataFrame.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.ceneo.pl/Laptopy;0020-30-0-0-1.htm")

names = []
prices = []
opinions = []

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml")

for a in soup.findAll('div', class_='cat-prod-row__content'):
    name=a.find('a', class_='go-to-product js_conv js_clickHash js_seoUrl')
    price=a.find('span', class_='value')
    rating=a.find('span', class_='product-score')
    names.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    opinions.append(rating.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Product name": names, "Price": prices, "Ratings": opinions})
print(df)
```

Comment: Do you need the data from that website, or do you need to use Selenium to get the data?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I am trying to get this from that website

Comment: Check my answer below and if it solved your issue, don't forget too mark it as accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Selenium (a testing tool, which should be the last resort for web scraping purposes) for this job, it can be accomplished with Python's Requests:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

s = requests.Session()
big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(0, 50)):
    soup = bs(s.get(f'https://www.ceneo.pl/Laptopy;0020-30-0-0-{x}.htm').text, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.select('div[class^="cat-prod-row js_category-list-item"]')
    for product in products:
        name = product.select_one('strong[class="cat-prod-row__name"]').get_text(strip=True)
        url = 'https://www.ceneo.pl' + product.select_one('strong[class="cat-prod-row__name"] a').get('href')
        price = product.select_one('span[class="price"]').get_text(strip=True)
        review = product.select_one('div[class="prod-review"]').get_text(strip=True)
        big_list.append((name, price, review, url))
big_df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['Product', 'Price', 'Review', 'Url'])
print(big_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
50/50 [00:58<00:00, 1.23s/it]
Product Price   Review  Url
0   PolecanyLaptop Microsoft Surface Pro 8 13"/i5/8GB/256GB/Win11 Grafitowy (8PQ-00019) 4 599,00    Napisz opinię   https://www.ceneo.pl/124614928
1   Laptop Apple MacBook Air 13,3"/M1/8GB/256GB/macOS (MGN63ZEA)    4 999,00    4,7/5101 opinii https://www.ceneo.pl/99105003
2   NowośćLaptop Asus Zenbook Pro 14 Duo 14"/i7/16GB/1000GB/Win11 (UX8402ZEM3047X)  11 299,00   Napisz opinię   https://www.ceneo.pl/140225545
3   Laptop Apple MacBook Pro 14,2"/M1 Pro/16GB/512GB/MacOS (MKGP3ZEA)   9 999,00    4,8/521 opinii  https://www.ceneo.pl/117018001
4   Laptop Apple MacBook Air 13,3"/M1/16GB/256GB/macOS (MGN63ZEAR1) 5 699,00    4,9/524 opinie  https://www.ceneo.pl/99146328
... ... ... ... ...
1495    Laptop ASUS ZenBook Flip OLED UX363 13,3"/i5/16GB/512GB/Win10 (UX363EA-HP293T)  5 399,00    5,0/51 opinia   https://www.ceneo.pl/Click/Offer/?e=aKBipmov74sdPT34-uY1ABp8pT37-qDRZhWm2arE84Y8alyehKPwqra3G-F1hpDbBVbIAB6nVaA-qO09a_bSN6Mdj_TjdpVYz3Jz2p5xzz3GDVZJ-oDjqVD5YwMxXzUxcGXlgcQta-MW6JVtTIoSjRBqT0FNHlU0GdHbfDah5aGRigon_xxT8qVQTMJZBQ3dpVBMwlkFDd0O6vJt7IMfgIYd0DNH9mPApVBMwlkFDd2lUEzCWQUN3da4SdAMteVBUjetPlzHcl2WcJyZM4d4kO0LIEurTCpG7QsgS6tMKkb_PeGTQbNaaKX-kaPaagvcCvOvQfahOqA_x-GY2zB2bQ==&a=2
1496    Laptop ASUS ROG Strix G17 17,3"/R7/16GB/1TB/Win11   9 999,00    Napisz opinię   https://www.ceneo.pl/128175532
1497    Laptop Asus Vivobook Pro 14 M3401QC-KM022W 14"/Ryzen7/16GB (90NB0VF2M01600) 4 899,00    Napisz opinię   https://www.ceneo.pl/129212935
1498    Laptop Asus VivoBook 14 X413EA 14"/i3/8GB/512GB/Win11 (X413EAEK2083)    2 349,00    Napisz opinię   https://www.ceneo.pl/130139751
1499    Laptop Asus X515EA-BQ1221W 15,6"/i3/16GB/256/Win11 (X515EABQ1221W)  1 999,99    Napisz opinię   https://www.ceneo.pl/135245766
1500 rows × 4 columns
```

See relevant documentation for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

For BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for TQDM: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/